# LAMP primers design software

Tags: primer, design

What software do you use to design LAMP reaction primers for alignment?  So far I have been using Primer Explorer v5 but I am looking for some alternatives.

Alignment includes some species from the same virus family. So I am looking for a set of primers that will capture species from the given alignment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is the depth of study and degeneracy, e.g. within a species, genera, or family ... or beyond? This is kinda important to identify which algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, woooaa thats difficult. I might have misunderstood this but if its an RNA virus diagnosis at the familial level that is not trivial. The mutation rate of RNA viruses is very high - at familial level, it's impossibly high excepting for the use of nested-PCR strategies.